# Get first and last day of navigated month in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a jQuery UI datepicker. When I click on previous and next arrow, I want to call an API and pass the navigated month's first and last day as date.

For e.g. if I go to August 2018 by clicking next, it should get first and last date of the month of August.

I am already getting it, but `onSelect`. I want to get it on navigation of previous and next.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/> 
<p id="date2"></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method

      var firstDay = new Date(dateAsObject.getFullYear(), dateAsObject.getMonth(), 1);
      var lastDay = new Date(dateAsObject.getFullYear(), dateAsObject.getMonth() + 1, 0);

      $('#date2').html(firstDay+" <br/> "+lastDay); 
   }
});
```

Check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/truhmevq/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using onSelect, Use onChangeMonthYear

```
$('#date1').datepicker({

    onChangeMonthYear : function(dateText, inst, dateob) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; 
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); 
      console.log(dateob.selectedDay +"/"+ dateob.selectedMonth +"/"+ dateob.selectedYear);
      var navidatedMonth = new Date(dateob.selectedYear, dateob.selectedMonth,  dateob.selectedDay)

     var firstDay = new Date(navidatedMonth.getFullYear(), navidatedMonth.getMonth(), 1);

      var lastDay = new Date(navidatedMonth.getFullYear(), navidatedMonth.getMonth() + 1, 0);

      $('#date2').html(firstDay + " <br/>" + lastDay); 

   }
});
```